# how to pass parameter with a href without refresh

Tags: php, html, href

How do I pass parameter value without refresh the page. Appreciate if anyone can help me. thanks.

**searchresult.php**

```
<a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $data['ID']?>">clickme</a>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>
```

Comment: Can you explaine what you want do? Because if you use a link like your code, you change the page so why you say about refresh

Comment: You're probably looking for _AJAX_.

Comment: i had try ajax but pass empty value, my goal is to click to open an overlay and at the same time pass the value in. but till now only this work, is there a method that i pass value by click without refresh the page

Answer (score 1):

For this issue you should try [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp).
Send your Data via JS to an PHP backend and recieve your data, without refreshing the page.

[AJAX with jquery.](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)

[AJAX example on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)